# Avoiding email2case spam when customers email helpdesk email and CC their coworkers

Tags: email2case, reference

Users are emailing helpdesk@org.com and CCing their coworkers. Then when the coworkers Reply All, there is no Ref ID (the unique ID that references the case) and another case gets created.

Anyone know of an elegant solution?

Comment: Is that a standard EmailToCase feature or a custom one?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by matching the incoming email's subject with existing cases, via Apex's Messaging.InboundEmail. 
A good post of such solution exists here:
http://sforcehacks.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/email-to-case-can-create-too-many-cases.html